# Does the Windows Forms DataGridView implement a true virtual mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a SQL table containing currently 1 million rows that will grow over time.

There is a specific user requirement to present a sortable grid that displays all rows without paging.  The user expects to be able to very quickly jump from row to row and top to bottom by using the scrollbar.

I am familiar with "virtual mode" grids that only present a visible subset of the overall data.  They can provide excellent UI performance and minimal memory requirements, (I've even implemented an application using this technique many years ago).

The Windows Forms DataGridView provides a virtual mode that looks like it should be the answer.  However unlike other virtual modes I've encountered, it still allocates memory for every row (confirmed in ProcessExplorer).  Obviously this causes overall memory usage to needlessly greatly increase and, while allocating these rows, there is a noticeable delay. Scrolling performance also suffers on 1 million + rows.

A real virtual mode would have no need to allocate any memory for rows not being displayed.  You just give it the total row count (eg 1,000,000) and all the grid does is scale the scrollbar accordingly.  When it is first displayed the grid simply asks for data the first n (say 30) visible rows only, instantaneous display.

When the user scrolls the grid, a simple row offset and the number of visible rows are provided and can be used to retrieve data from the data store.

Here's an example of the DataGridView code I'm currently using:

```
public void AddVirtualRows(int rowCount)
{
    dataGridList.ColumnCount = 4;


    dataGridList.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
    dataGridList.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;

    dataGridList.VirtualMode = true;

    dataGridList.RowCount = rowCount;

    dataGridList.CellValueNeeded += new DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridList_CellValueNeeded);


}
void dataGridList_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    e.Value = e.RowIndex;
}
```

Am I missing anything here, or is the "virtual" mode of the DataGridView not really virtual at all?

[Update]

It looks like the good old ListView implements exactly the sort of virtual mode I'm looking for.  But unfortunately the ListView does not have the cell formatting capabilities of the DataGridView, so I can't use it.

For others that might be able to, I tested it with a four column ListView (in Detail mode), VirtualMode= True and VirtualListSize =100,000,000 rows.

The list is displayed immediately with the first 30 rows visible.  I can then scroll rapidly to the bottom of the list with no delay.  The memory usage is constant 10 MB at all times.

Comment: Check out these articles (if you haven't already): [How to: Implement Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx) [Paging Data with DataGridView in VirtualMode](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewPaging.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

We just had a similar requirement to be able to display arbitrary, unindexed 1M+ row tables in our application with "very good" performance, using the stock `DataGridView`.  At first I thought it wasn't possible, but with enough head scratching, we came up with something that works very well after spending days pouring over Reflector and .NET Profiler.  **This was difficult to do, but the results were well worth it.**

The way we tackled this problem was by creating a class that implements `ITypedList` and `IBindingList` (you can call it `LargeTableView`, for example) to manage the asynchronous retrieval and caching of information from the database.  We also created a single PropertyDescriptor-inheriting class (e.g. `LargeTableColumnDescriptor`) to retrieve data from each column.

When the `DataGridView.DataSource` property is set to a class implementing `IBindingList`, it goes into a **pseudo-virtual mode** that differs from regular VirtualMode, where as when each row is painted (such as when the user scrolls), the DataGridView accesses the indexer [] on the `IBindingList` and the respective `GetValue` methods on each column's `PropertyDescriptor` to retrieve the values as needed.  The `CellValueNeeded` event is not raised.  In our case, we access the database when the indexer is accessed, and then cache the value, so that subsequent re-paints don't hit the database.

I performed similar tests re: memory usage.  The `DataGridView` does allocate an array that is the size of the list (i.e. 1M rows), however each item in the array initially references a single DataGridViewRow, so memory usage is acceptible.  I am not sure if the behavior is the same when VirtualMode is true.  **We were able to eliminate scroll lag** by immediately returning `String.Empty` in the `GetValue` method if the row is not cached, and then performing the database query asynchronously.  When the async request is finished, you can raise the `IBindingList.ListChanged` event to signal to the DataGridView that it should repaint the cells, except this time reading from the cache which is readily available.  That way, the UI is never blocked waiting for database calls.

One thing we noticed is that performance is significantly better if you set the DataSource or number of virtual rows **before** adding the DataGridView to the form - it cut initialization time in half.  Also, make sure that you have both Row and Column autosizing set to `None` or else you will have additional performance problems.

*Side note: the way we accomplished "loading" such a large table in our .NET application was by creating a temporary table on the SQL server that listed the primary keys in the desired sort order along with an IDENTITY (row number), and then persisting the connection for subsequent row requests.  This naturally takes time to initialize (approx. 3-5s on a reasonably fast SQL server), but without knowledge of available indexes, we have no better alternative.  Then, in our ITypedList implementation, we request rows in pages of 100 rows, where the 50th row is the row that is being painted, so that we limit the number of queries performed each time the indexer is accessed, and that we give the appearance of having all of the data available in our application.*

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404298.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx

Comment: i tried reproducing the implementation you describe, but i hit several problems. 1) when i set grid.DataSource to my bindinglist it asks for the count and all the entities immediatly 2) i couldnt manage yet calls to the indexer while data is still fetching 3) invalidating the cache when sortorder is changed whild data is still fetching returning stale results

Comment: Try returning a count of 0 if you haven't completed the background fetch yet.  If you would like to send me some of your code, I would be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **NO**

[see first comment here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624.aspx)

if anyone knows a better way please tell us

Comment: I think the link points to the most recenet version and the comment is not visible there. Is it the commetn that starts "This example doesn't appear to work using .NET 4.0"?

Comment: i don't know anymore but i guess it was ".NET Framework 3.0" noentheless "Visual Studio 2010" is also interesting

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes... as long as you stick to the events triggered by the Virtual Mode behavior (e.g. CellValueNeeded) and that you take good care of clearing your hand built-buffer. I already displayed large amount of data, more than 1M without a fuss.

I'm a little bit curious about the implementation of Kevin McCormick using a DataSource based on ITypedList or any IList related interface implementations. I guess it's just yet another abstraction layer who makes the use of an internal and transparent buffer in addition to let the user or the developer powers the DataGridView with this, but still internally dealing with the native VirtualMode to display the information you have loaded in the buffer.

Besides of the fashion way to workaround the virtual mode, to me, the the only tough problem remaining with the DataGridView is the RowCount limitation: it's still a Int32.Max.  It is probably due to the legacy of the Winforms Drawing System... just like the Images or even every Size Members, Width, Height of Winform Controls... why not stick to a UInt32 Type?

I assume that nobody has seen a Control or a picture with negative dimensions, but still the type is not properly appropriate to the context of use.

See my answer there below, could help you if you are still stuck with that trouble, event if, I guess it's already resolved for ages now.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16373108/1906567