# Windows Forms Control - Huge list of filenames

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Which control would be best for showing a huge (300.000+) list of filenames?

I've tried DataGridView, but it seems to be overkill and also slow.

Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Have you evaluated using the DataGridView in "virtual" mode : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx ?

Comment: Also suggest you check out Phillip Piper's "A much easier to use ListView" on CodeProject : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx This article was started in 2006, updated many times, now supports a virtual mode, and Phillip is still responding to comments and questions as of this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard ListView control has a [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx) designed specifically for your situation.  I've used it with a million row list previously and it does the job well.

It is a true virtual mode.  In other words memory allocation and list population time remains low regardless of the size of the overall list.  This is unlike the [DataGridView that really starts to slowdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020819/does-the-windows-forms-datagridview-implement-a-true-virtual-mode) and use memory on large lists.

To use virtual mode set:

```
VirtualListMode = true
VirtualListSize= 300000
```

(or whatever size your list currently is)

Then handle the RetrieveVirtualItem event to populate the list on demand from your list.  You may also wnat/need to handle the CacheVirtualItems and SearchForVirtualItem events.

Answer (score 4):

None.

No USER will be able to handle a single list of 300.000+ entries in a meaningful way. Looks like your design is seriously flawed - do you really have to present the complete list?

Consider using a search box and let the users search the file names (use auto completion/suggestions like Google et.al.) or create a separate list for every starting letter (like most address books do). Or find another way to reduce the number of entries from which the user has to select.

Comment: -1 I just knew someone would feel the need to give their opinion rather actually answering the question.  There are situations where this IS a reasonable approach, how do you know the OP hasn't considered other options already?  Regardless, the standard WinForms ListView has a virtual mode specifically for displaying large (up to multiple-million) lists of data.

Comment: Useless response, trying to discourage someone from writing software that doesn't explode on large directories.

Answer (score 0):

Set up pagination and restrict the number of rows displayed by the DataGrid. You can add a combobox to jump between pages. This is a standard solution.

also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125963/need-help-in-gridview-and-table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ListView with report style? This is the control used by Windows natively in its file browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from gotch4's answer. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewPaging.aspx) is a good article from CodeProject on how to do paging with a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out ObjectListView, specifically the VirtualObjectListView:

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

I forget off hand what license it has been released under so you might want to look at that before using it in a commercial application.