# DataGridView Optimization

Tags: c#, caching, optimization, datagridview

I'm trying to optimize my over-slow DataGridView, which use a SQLite Database for getting data using the virtual mode and a cache, I already use the trick of the Double Buffering and to remove the autosize for columns and rows. However, in spite of reading this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx
and that : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx

My grid is super slow, actually the queries to the DB are pretty fast but seems the painting of the DataGridView is super slow even when the data are already loaded through the cache...

But maybe my Cache class is not *that* good so I'm wondering if I did something wrong. The principle is quite simple, a Cache divided into 3 parts: Upper, Current (could also be called "Middle" and Lower), each is delimited by indexes (start & end), if a data is already loaded, the Cache gonna give the value according to those very simple rules:

- if value is in the current part no problem, just load the data
- if value needed is whether in the upper or lower, no problems this part becomes the current one and only a new part is required.

i.e.

Upper Part: 0 - 100
Current Part: 101 - 201
Lower Part : 202 - 302

The value need is within the Lower Part, no problems, Current becomes Lower, Upper turns into Current and only the new Lower part needs to be reloaded. Obviously, if the value needed has a row index not avaible with the Cache, this one is reloaded.

```cs
public class Cache
{
    private Dictionary<PagePart, Page> _pages;
    public Dictionary<PagePart, Page> Pages
    {
        get { return this._pages; }
        set { this._pages = value; }
    }

    private String _tableName;
    public String TableName
    {
        get { return this._tableName; }
        set { this._tableName = value; }
    }

    private SQLiteConnection _connection;
    public SQLiteConnection Connection
    {
        get { return this._connection; }
        set { this._connection = value; }
    }

    public Cache(String tableName, SQLiteConnection connection)
    {
        this.Connection = connection;
        this.TableName = tableName;

        this.Pages = new Dictionary<PagePart, Page>(PageNumber);

        IndexRange indexRangeUpper = new IndexRange(0, PageSize);
        IndexRange indexRangeCurrent = new IndexRange(PageSize + 1, 2 * PageSize);
        IndexRange indexRangeLower = new IndexRange(2 * PageSize + 1, 3 * PageSize);

        DataTable dataTableUpper = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeUpper);
        DataTable dataTableCurrent = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeCurrent);
        DataTable dataTableLower = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeLower);

        Page pageUpper = new Page(indexRangeUpper, dataTableUpper);
        Page pageCurrent = new Page(indexRangeCurrent, dataTableCurrent);
        Page pageLower = new Page(indexRangeLower, dataTableLower);

        Pages.Add(PagePart.Upper, pageUpper);
        Pages.Add(PagePart.Current, pageCurrent);
        Pages.Add(PagePart.Lower, pageLower);
    }

    private IndexRange GetTableIndexRange()
    {
        String commandText = String.Format("SELECT MAX(RowId) FROM {0}", this.TableName);
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, this.Connection);

        this.Connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        String maxRowIdString = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        this.Connection.Close();

        Int32 maxRowId = Int32.Parse(maxRowIdString);

        return new IndexRange(0, maxRowId);
    }

    public Object GetCellValue(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 columnIndex)
    {
        Int32 indexLowerStart = Pages[PagePart.Lower].Range.StartIndex;
        Int32 indexLowerEnd = Pages[PagePart.Lower].Range.EndIndex;

        Int32 indexCurrentStart = Pages[PagePart.Current].Range.StartIndex;
        Int32 indexCurrentEnd = Pages[PagePart.Current].Range.EndIndex;

        Int32 indexUpperStart = Pages[PagePart.Upper].Range.StartIndex;
        Int32 indexUpperEnd = Pages[PagePart.Upper].Range.EndIndex;

        IndexRange indexRangeTable = this.GetTableIndexRange();
        Int32 indexTableStart = indexRangeTable.StartIndex;
        Int32 indexTableEnd = indexRangeTable.EndIndex;

        // Using the cache...
        if ((indexUpperStart <= rowIndex) && (rowIndex <= indexLowerEnd))
        {
            if ((indexLowerStart <= rowIndex) && (rowIndex <= indexLowerEnd))
            {
                if (indexTableEnd > indexLowerEnd)
                {
                    this.Pages[PagePart.Upper] = this.Pages[PagePart.Current];
                    this.Pages[PagePart.Current] = this.Pages[PagePart.Lower];

                    IndexRange indexRangeLower = new IndexRange(this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Range.EndIndex + 1, this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Range.EndIndex + PageSize);
                    DataTable dataTableLower = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeLower);

                    Page pageLower = new Page(indexRangeLower, dataTableLower);

                    this.Pages[PagePart.Lower] = pageLower;

                    Int32 pageSize = this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows.Count;
                    return this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows[rowIndex % pageSize][columnIndex];
                }
                else
                {
                    Int32 pageSize = this.Pages[PagePart.Lower].Data.Rows.Count;
                    return this.Pages[PagePart.Lower].Data.Rows[rowIndex % pageSize][columnIndex];
                }
            }

            if ((indexCurrentStart <= rowIndex) && (rowIndex <= indexCurrentEnd))
            {
                Int32 pageSize = this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows.Count;
                return this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows[rowIndex % pageSize][columnIndex];
            }

            if ((indexUpperStart <= rowIndex) && (rowIndex <= indexUpperEnd))
            {
                if (indexTableStart < indexUpperStart)
                {
                    this.Pages[PagePart.Lower] = this.Pages[PagePart.Current];
                    this.Pages[PagePart.Current] = this.Pages[PagePart.Upper];

                    IndexRange indexRangeUpper = new IndexRange(this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Range.StartIndex - 1, this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Range.EndIndex - PageSize);
                    DataTable dataTableUpper = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeUpper);

                    Page pageUpper = new Page(indexRangeUpper, dataTableUpper);

                    this.Pages[PagePart.Upper] = pageUpper;

                    Int32 pageSize = this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows.Count;
                    return this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows[rowIndex % pageSize][columnIndex];
                }
                else
                {
                    Int32 pageSize = this.Pages[PagePart.Upper].Data.Rows.Count;
                    return this.Pages[PagePart.Upper].Data.Rows[rowIndex % pageSize][columnIndex];
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        // Need to reload the cache...
        else
        {
            IndexRange indexRangeCurrent = new IndexRange(rowIndex - (PageSize / 2), rowIndex + (PageSize / 2));
            IndexRange indexRangeLower = new IndexRange(indexRangeCurrent.EndIndex + 1, indexRangeCurrent.EndIndex + PageSize);
            IndexRange indexRangeUpper = new IndexRange(indexRangeCurrent.StartIndex - 1, indexRangeCurrent.StartIndex - PageSize );

            DataTable dataTableUpper = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeUpper);
            DataTable dataTableCurrent = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeCurrent);
            DataTable dataTableLower = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeLower);

            Page pageUpper = new Page(indexRangeUpper, dataTableUpper);
            Page pageCurrent = new Page(indexRangeCurrent, dataTableCurrent);
            Page pageLower = new Page(indexRangeLower, dataTableLower);

            Pages[PagePart.Upper] = pageUpper;
            Pages[PagePart.Current] = pageCurrent;
            Pages[PagePart.Lower] = pageLower;

            Int32 pageSize = this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows.Count;
            return this.Pages[PagePart.Current].Data.Rows[rowIndex % pageSize][columnIndex];
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetDataTableFromTable(IndexRange indexRange)
    {
        if (this.Connection != null)
        {
            String commandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE RowId BETWEEN {1} AND {2}", this.TableName, indexRange.StartIndex, indexRange.EndIndex);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, this.Connection);
            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(this.TableName, this.TableName);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return dataTable;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private const Int32 PageNumber = 3;
    private const Int32 PageSize = 128;

    public class Page
    {
        public Page(IndexRange range, DataTable data)
        {
            this.Range = range;
            this.Data = data;
        }

        private IndexRange _range;
        public IndexRange Range
        {
            get { return this._range; }
            set { this._range = value; }
        }

        private DataTable _data;
        public DataTable Data
        {
            get { return this._data; }
            set { this._data = value; }
        }
    }
    public enum PagePart
    {
        Upper,
        Current,
        Lower,
    }

    public class IndexRange
    {
        private Int32 _startIndex;
        public Int32 StartIndex
        {
            get { return this._startIndex; }
            set { this._startIndex = value; }
        }

        private Int32 _endIndex;
        public Int32 EndIndex
        {
            get { return this._endIndex; }
            set { this._endIndex = value; }
        }

        public IndexRange(Int32 startIndex, Int32 stopIndex)
        {
            this.StartIndex = startIndex;
            this.EndIndex = stopIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

But gee... the painting is so slow... what can I do...?

Comment: Populate a DataTable which represents your expected datagridview. 
Then use the DataSource property of the DataGridView to link it to the DataTable. That will speed things up alot.

Comment: The DataSource property is okay as long as the so-called DataSource has a loading time acceptable, I deal with hundreds of thousands of records (basically the SQLite Database file is about more than one GigaByte), it takes (when the ui does not start to freeze before) roughly 15 minutes to load the whole set of data to the DataSource. That's why I decided to use the Virtual Mode in order to load only the current view of information required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way for answering to my own question, I just used a primary key to avoid any confusion about the offset whether I scroll up or down (yeah lazy way, so it's not that... efficient but still more than just without cache at all and pretty easy to use [i.e. without using 3 caches but finally it comes up with only one for doing properly the job]):

```cs
public class Cache
{
    protected SQLiteConnection Connection { get; set; }
    protected String TableName { get; set; }
    protected const Int32 PageSize = 512;

    protected CachePage PageCurrent { get; set; }
    protected IndexRange IndexRangeTable { get; set; }

    public Cache(SQLiteConnection connection, String tableName)
    {
        SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();

        this.Connection = connection;
        this.TableName = tableName;

        IndexRange indexRangeCurrent = new IndexRange(0, PageSize - 1);
        DataTable dataTableCurrent = this.GetDataTableFromTable(indexRangeCurrent);

        this.PageCurrent = new CachePage(indexRangeCurrent, dataTableCurrent);
    }

    public Object GetCellValue(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 columnIndex)
    {
        DataRow dataRowFound = this.PageCurrent.Data.Rows.Find(rowIndex);

        if (dataRowFound != null)
        {
            return dataRowFound[columnIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            this.ShiftPageToIndex(rowIndex);

            return GetCellValue(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }

    private void ShiftPageToIndex(Int32 index)
    {
        this.PageCurrent.Range.Start = index;
        this.PageCurrent.Range.Stop = index + PageSize;
        this.PageCurrent.Data = this.GetDataTableFromTable(this.PageCurrent.Range);

        this.PageCurrent.Range.Start = index;
        this.PageCurrent.Range.Stop = index + this.PageCurrent.Data.Rows.Count;
    }

    private IndexRange GetTableIndexRange()
    {
        String commandText = String.Format("SELECT MAX(RowId) FROM {0}", this.TableName);
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, this.Connection);

        this.Connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        String maxRowIdString = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        this.Connection.Close();

        Int32 maxRowId = Int32.Parse(maxRowIdString);

        return new IndexRange(0, maxRowId);
    }
    private DataTable GetDataTableFromTable(IndexRange indexRange)
    {
        if (this.Connection != null)
        {
            String commandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE RowId BETWEEN {1} AND {2}", this.TableName, indexRange.Start, indexRange.Stop);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, this.Connection);
            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(this.TableName, this.TableName);

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            dataTable.Columns.Add("RowId", typeof(Int64));

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataTable.Rows[i]["RowId"] = i + indexRange.Start;
            }

            dataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataTable.Columns["Rowid"] };

            return dataTable;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
public class CachePage
{
    public CachePage(IndexRange range, DataTable data)
    {
        this.Range = range;
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public IndexRange Range {get; set;}
    public DataTable Data {get; set;}
} 
public class IndexRange
{
    public Int32 Start {get; set;}
    public Int32 Stop { get; set; }

    public IndexRange(Int32 start, Int32 stop)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.Stop = stop;
    }
}
```

// How to call it from a dummy DataGridView?

```
private void dataGridViewMain_CellValueNeeded(Object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Cache != null)
        {
            e.Value = this.Cache.GetCellValue(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
        }
    }
```

So it's pretty cool and works well without a fuss and without thinking that much...

This snippet can be used to create a SQLite database table viewer using the RowId field instead of Primary Key (which is actually not really a field).

Another better solution would be to get data in order by...asc or desc and then to look for such data using modulo operatorbut I'm too lazy for that task. I guess the SQLite dll is still faster to get order in data than using a pre-existing DataColumn as a PrimaryKey... but as I said I'm quite lazy for now...