# Populating DataGridView from background thread

Tags: c#, datagridview

This question has been asked a lot, and I've read all the posts on Stackoverflow on it.

I wanted to confirm my conclusion though.

Where the source of information being populated is quite fast (ie it doesn't take much processing time to get the information itself), it seems to me that the processing that takes the time is actually feeding it into the DataGridView. However that has to be done on the UI thread as that's where the control is.

If that's the case there seems to be limited benefit to trying to do anything in the background, and that the corollary is that there's no effective way to populate a DataGridView without bunging up the UI thread. Is that right?

Surely there must somehow be a way to populate a DataGridView entirely asynchronously while the user can still interact with the UI?

Comment: How many data at a time can a user see. How many data are you trying to put into your view. Where is your bottleneck? add you technology tag - winfowms? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020819/does-the-windows-forms-datagridview-implement-a-true-virtual-mode

Comment: Wrong.  The time to update the DGV is the time to refresh the DGV.  So normally only doing the refresh at the end will speed up the code.  Best method is to make the DataSource of the DGV a DataTable and then in background mode update the DataTable.  Then at the end set the updated DataTable to the DatSource.

Comment: I'm only adding a few hundred rows, but some of them have a significant amount of text. I've also tried disabling the DataGridView during update, and suspending the layout but performance is still not optimal. It looks like the Data Table route is worth a try, so I'll look at that.

Comment: There seems to be a good example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control   Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this.  I'm populating a DataTable in the background thread, which is pretty much instantaneous.  Then, I assign that DataTable to the BindingSource that the DataGridView is pointing at.  I have to assign the DataTable to the BindingSource on the UI thread, otherwise I get a cross-thread exception.  BUT, executing the single line "sql_query_results.DataSource = query_results;" takes about 5-10 seconds, which is slower than it was when I did the whole lot on the UI thread and filled the DataGridView directly.  Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: After trying many different ways of doing this and profiling them, the biggest lag is actually within the DataGridView, and is the same whether you try binding using a DataTable all in one go or populating the rows inidividually straight into the DGV.  In the end I just populated the DataGridView asynchronously from a worker thread, with a progress bar etc so at least it looks pretty.  Not as quick as I'd hoped but works satisfactorily and doesn't bung up the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely there must somehow be a way to populate a DataGridView entirely asynchronously while the user can still interact with the UI?

There are many ways it can be done.

### Paging via Async/await Inlined with Regular Code

If whatever it is you are fetching the data from (whether it be a direct database connection; REST or WCF call) supports paging, then you could fetch pages of data via inline `async/await` and add rows for each item returned in the page.

e.g.

```
// somewhere in your UI code

async Task LoadAsync(List<Page> pages)
{
    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        var stuff = await service.GetMovieSalesPagedAsync (page);

        foreach (var item in stuff)
        {
            _dataGrid.Rows.Add (/* convert item then add it here  */);  
        }        
    }
}
```

This is faster than say requesting all the data in one go and then trying to add rows for each item.  The latter would just block the UI.

The benefit of the above approach is that the code is inline and easier to read.

### Dedicated Task with Progressive Filling During Application Idle

This technique is better for when there is a large amount of data to display and you want the best performance UI-wise.  It's also useful if the source does not support paging.

Here you can spawn a `Task` whose job is to retrieve the data a page (or all at once) at a time, then add each page results to say a `ConcurrentQueue<>` for the benefit of the UI thread.  If you have to retrieve all of it, then break the results into pages manually.

Meanwhile, in your `Application.Idle` handler try to pop an item off the queue and if one is found, add the new items as rows to the datagrid.  Now depending on your app, you may choose to process all available pages or wait for the next application idle event.  It might take a bit of fine tuning.  Waiting for the next application idle allows your app to play nice with UI responsiveness.

This will cause the datagrid to be filled progressively rather than all at once.

A con of this approach is that the code is no longer inline.  You have one block of code responsible for fetching and storing data; another for pumping it into the UI.